# QGIS 25D shapefiles

Tags: qgis, 3d, gpx

I do know QGIS doesnt so far make use of 25/3D files, but

If I do make use of 3D points from a say GPX file and thereafter, using snap, generate a new polygone shapefile. Will the z-coords be kept als 2.5/3D or will they be lost?

Answer (score 1):

i haven't generated 25D polygons, but i have created linestrings with a z-coordinate. I'm able to view the lines in 3D in software other than QGIS (currently using [visit](https://wci.llnl.gov/simulation/computer-codes/visit)).
of course, i can still view the features in QGIS, just 2D.